# R Shiny reactive select Input

Tags: r, shiny

I keep getting an error when I try and make my select Input in R shiny reactive on another select Input.  I've tried renderUi and updateSelectizeInput without success. I'd prefer to use updateSelectize as this is in keeping with the rest of the app.

I want the second select input to be the column names of columns that are not NA. Here is some cut down code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(c(NA, NA, NA, 4, 6, 2, 1, 6, NA, NA), ncol = 5, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)), c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"))
df <- cbind(data.frame(ID = c("a", "b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), df)

all_drop_options <- df %>% pull(ID)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = "SID",
                       choices = all_drop_options, selected = "a",
                       server = TRUE)

  new_dat <- reactive({
    df %>% filter(ID == input$SID)
  })

  year_opts2 <- reactive({
    new_dat() %>%
      select(-ID) %>%
      select_if(~!is.na(.)) %>% colnames()
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = "yr",
                         choices = year_opts2()
    )})
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "SID", label = NULL,
              choices = "a", selected = "a"),

  selectInput(inputId = "yr", label = "",choices = "")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
new_dat <- reactive({
    df %>% filter(ID == input$SID)
  })
```

Trying to evaluate that inside of `reactve()` won't work. Simply put the `df %>% filter(ID == input$SID)` in place of:

`new_dat()`

so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(c(NA, NA, NA, 4, 6, 2, 1, 6, NA, NA), ncol = 5, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)), c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5"))
df <- cbind(data.frame(ID = c("a", "b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), df)

all_drop_options <- df %>% pull(ID)



ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "SID", label = NULL,
              choices = "a", selected = "a"),

  selectInput(inputId = "yr", label = "",choices = "")
)


server <- function(input, output, session){

  updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = "SID",
                       choices = all_drop_options, selected = "a",
                       server = TRUE)


  year_opts2 <- reactive({
    tryCatch({
    df %>% filter(ID == input$SID) %>%
      select(-ID) %>%
      select_if(~!is.na(.)) %>% colnames()},
    error = function(x){
      return('')
    })
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = "yr",
                         choices = year_opts2()
    )})
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## edit:

As you noted, the script sometimes bugs because the `filter` returns an empty dataframe occasionally by error which stops `colnames()` from excecuting.

I added a `tryCatch` to mitigate for this but not entirely sure why it's happening!

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your suggestion but I'm still getting this error: Warning: Error in <-: replacement has length zero

Comment: It worked for me. I'll take another look later but try re-saving the script and re-starting your R session?

Comment: @chris20 ok yeah something else is going on. It works when I run it sometimes but I get the error occasionally too. I'll take another look

Comment: Yes it works now - that's great thanks. I wonder if input$SID is returning null sometimes which gives the filter error.  Anyway the trycatch seems to have fixed it, will write it into the rest of the app and make sure it works there.

Answer (score 0):

## Background:

For some reasons "I don't know about them" in the 2nd `reactive`, `new_dat()` become null after the 1st iteration, So`select_if` does what should be done and generates this error.

```
#Run this code for better understanding
observe(print(new_dat()))

year_opts2 <- reactive({
   browser()
 new_dat() %>%
   select(-ID) %>%
   select_if(~!is.na(.)) %>%
   colnames()

})

observe(print(year_opts2()))
```

Now, if we comment `browser()` and  `select_if(~!is.na(.))` code will work without any errors. Like so

```
observe(print(new_dat()))

year_opts2 <- reactive({
#browser()
 new_dat() %>%
   select(-ID) %>%
  #select_if(~!is.na(.)) %>%
   colnames()

})

observe(print(year_opts2()))
```

## Solution:

Hopefully, below will solve your problem

```
year_opts2 <- reactive({
 colnames(new_dat()[,!is.na(new_dat())][-1])
})
```